# Would exhaust gas recuperation increase forced induction ICE thermal efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics

I see high performance modern turbocharged ICEs utilize intercooler between turbocharger and ICE intake. I was wondering if we forget high performance label and focus on thermal efficiency, would recuperating heat from exhaust gas and heating intake air after compressor improve thermal efficiency?

Compressor -> Recuperator[A] -> ICE -> Turbine -> Recuperator[B]

Recuperator[A] and Recuperator[B] are the same part

Obviously this scheme would reduce power output and require modifications to compression ratio specification, but would this improve thermal efficiency in the same way that regenerator improves Stirling cycle? (Applicable to Brayton cycle too, I suppose)

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but on a related subject affecting how worthwhile it might be: Important to not neglect the harmful effects of [pre-ignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-ignition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preheating the inlet charge by recuperating the exhaust heat does indeed improve *thermal efficiency* and for example was used in the prototype turbine car engines designed by Chrysler in the early 1960's.

But because preheating the incoming air reduces its density, the engine can support less fuel combustion per unit of time in this case and power output goes down. This is why intercooling is commonly used with turbochargers to maximize the total amount of O2 entering the engine per unit of time by maximizing the *density* of the incoming charge.

In this connection it is worth noting that an exhaust-driven turbine is itself extracting extra work from the heat being rejected by the engine and adding it (in one way or another) to the mechanical power output of the engine.

For example, the 18-cylinder Wright R-3350 aircraft engine had 3 exhaust-driven power recovery turbines coupled to the crankshaft of the engine which recovered about 450 net horsepower at cruise conditions- power which would otherwise be lost in the exhaust plume. In the case of the 3350, it had a mechanically-driven supercharger with no intercooling- since it was typically operating in subzero temperature conditions between 25,000 and 30,000 feet.